# how to limit cmb2 to specific page templates

Tags: php, wordpress

I want cmb2 to be displayed in posts that have a movie template
I use this code :

```
$cmb_review = new_cmb2_box( array(
'id' => $prefix . 'metabox',
'title' => __( "My title", 'cmb2' ),
'object_types' => array( 'post'),
'show_on'      => array( 'key' => 'page-template', 'value' => 'movie.php' )
));
```

but that doesn't work

I also tried this code but it didn't work :

```
function maybe_show($cmb_review ) {

  $template = get_post_meta( $cmb_review ->object_id(), 'page-template', true );
  if ( 'movie.php' === $template ) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

$cmb_review = new_cmb2_box( array(
'id' => $prefix . 'metabox',
'title' => __( "My title", 'cmb2' ),
'object_types' => array( 'post'),
'show_on_cb' => 'maybe_show'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your meta box object type is post and is your template page for post too?

Make sure both match.